# How to get the EditText username into .whereEqualTo. FireStore?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, textview

How can I as an Admin, Look for another user by typing its name(/Naam), and project/set its "tegoed" into a textview?

[EDIT: I do get a TextView when hardcoded "Anne" at WhereEqualTo, But I have no idea how to make this work with an EditText where I can fill in someones name]

[My Firestore is build like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0G9DE.png)
, both fields are Strings for now. but the numbers will be numbers after testing

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tegoedaanvullen);

    Naamtgd = findViewById(R.id.etNaamtgd);
    Tegoed = findViewById(R.id.etTgd);
    tvTegoed = findViewById(R.id.tvTgd);
    btnZoek = findViewById(R.id.btnZoek);
    btnVulAan = findViewById(R.id.btnVulAan);
    btnTerug = findViewById(R.id.btnTerug);
    NAAM = Naamtgd.getText().toString();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();


    btnZoek.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            fStore.collection("Gebruikers")
                    .whereEqualTo("Naam", "Anne")
                    .get()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(Tegoedaanvullen.this, "Gelukt?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                             tvTegoed.setText(document.getString("Tegoed"));


                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(Tegoedaanvullen.this, "Mislukt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        }
                    });
        }
    });
```

I think this might be interesting, when I hard-code "ANNE" the word : Value , appears. It doesnt when I put in the String: NAAM;

[click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9xIU.png)

[NEW LOGS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdAY0.png)

Comment: Just provide the database structure

Comment: I dit edited my post and provided a database structure.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have now?  Please edit the question to explain what's not working the way you expect.

Comment: I adjusted my post. But the textview stays empty...

Comment: Again, what's wrong with what you have now?  We can't see the value of `NAAM`, so we can't tell if you're querying correctly.  Try hard coding the value first to get the query working, then figure out why the current value isn't correct.

Comment: @DougStevenson He is retrieving the list of docs from query he can't set them

Comment: @DougStevenson The hardcodes one DOES work! But how do I make it work by writing the name into the Edittekst

Comment: Could you please print what document contains? Please try the following code and see if you can view your name in the text View:

***tvTegoed.setText(document.getData().get("Tegoed");***

Comment: That does not work: Cannot resolve method 'setText(java.lang.Object)'

Comment: @NibrassH When I hardcode "Anne" it prints "10" into the Textview. Is that what you mean?

Comment: No No, I mean please put NAAM in whereEqualTo as following:

***.whereEqualTo("Naam", NAAM)***;

Comment: When I put in NAAM it does not print anything. Thats the thing I hope to achieve. And this:** tvTegoed.setText(document.getData().get("Tegoed"); **  gives this error :  **Cannot resolve method 'setText(java.lang.Object)' **

Comment: Could you then please try to print out in the Console what contains document?

Comment: Thanks for helping, please check the edited post for your asnwer. I hope I did it well.

Comment: Reached this point, could you please show all the logs you have written (screenshot)? What type is NAAM ? What does NAAM prints to the Console?

Comment: @NibrassH I found some error:  NAAM = Naamtgd.getText().toString(); This is a part that didnt work. Fixed that

Comment: @NibrassH And I added some Logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. With help of the Logs!

String NAAM = Edittext.getText.toString was typed before the button was pressed, in OnCreate.

So, it already being filled at the second I opened the page.

Now, it's in the .setOnClicklistener, and it works!